# Algolia search python client to upload indexes behind a firewall

Tags: python-3.x, search, algolia

Building a search with Algolia search product for our Moodle site.
To update the index at Algolia site we want to use some automated process (upload the index data).
I decided to start with the Python client (Python v 3.9.x). Since we are working inside a corporate network we are behind the firewalls and there is a problem accessing algolia's servers.
I'm testing with two methods:

1. Search within already existing indices: index.search
2. update all indexes: index.replace_all_objects
   Error message:  'Unreachable hosts'

Here is my code snippets:

```
# Search:
searchAppID = constants.ALGOLIA_APP_ID
searchKeyHash = constants.ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY
config = SearchConfig(searchAppID, searchKeyHash) 
config.connect_timeout = 2
config.read_timeout = 5
config.write_timeout =  30 
client = SearchClient.create_with_config(config)
index = client.init_index('myIndex')
result = index.search('SearchString')
```

```
# function to update index using json file:

def replace_IdxObj(client,index,fileName):
    try:
        if (index.exists()):                 
            with open(fileName, encoding="utf8") as f:
                data = json.load(f)                        
                result = index.replace_all_objects(data, { 'autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist' : True })
            return result
        else:            
            print('No Index found! Cancel operation... \n')
            return None        
        
    except Exception as err:
         print ("Error: " + str(err))
```

When I test my code outside of the company's network - it's all ok!

Also I have a SSL certificate that could be used to work with external resources, so I used it in the following test (running from company's network behind the firewall):

```
response = requests.get('https://google.com/',  verify=("C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\SSL\\certs\\cert.cer"))  
print(response)
```

This test works just fine (I'm getting 200 response)!

Please advise are there any ways to make Python process (which is used by algolia's python client) to use the certificate that I have ??? Any alternatives?
Many thanks!

Comment: So far i have not received any suggestions, here is my own workaround I found: 
Since I'm able to use PHP with my windows certs, I managed to use PHP-algolia client to send the index outside. Example: 
1) Python script to fetch the index and save into JSON file
2) Call the PHP-algolia client and pass some params (keys, json file) 
3) Once PHP send required index to the external server, get the result (use wait() to be sure that all done)
4) Analyze the result in Python script